# Column operation on Spark RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with MANY columns (e.g. hundreds), and most of my operation is on columns, e.g. I need to create many intermediate variables from different columns.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

For example, if my `dataRDD[Array[String]]` is like below:

```
123, 523, 534, ..., 893 
536, 98, 1623, ..., 98472 
537, 89, 83640, ..., 9265 
7297, 98364, 9, ..., 735 
...... 
29, 94, 956, ..., 758
```

I will need to create a new column or a variable as `newCol1 = 2ndCol+19thCol`, and another new column based on `newCol1` and the existing columns: `newCol2 = function(newCol1, 34thCol)`.

What is the best way of doing this?

I have been thinking using index for the intermediate variables and the `dataRDD`, and then join them together on the index to do my calculation:

```
var dataRDD = sc.textFile("/test.csv").map(_.split(","))
val dt = dataRDD.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
val newCol1 = dataRDD.map(x => x(1)+x(18)).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
val newCol2 = newCol1.join(dt).map(x=> function(.........))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do it all in one:

```
var dataRDD = sc.textFile("/test.csv").map(_.split(","))
dataRDD.map(x=>{
  val newCol = x(1) + x(18)
  val newCol2 = function(newCol, x(33))
  //anything else you need to do
  newCol +: newCol2 +: x //This will return the original array with the new columns prepended
  //x +: newCol +: newCol2 //Alternatively, this will return the original array with the new columns appended
})
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for your reply. I might have misunderstood your point. But when I tried something like "dataRDD.map(x => {val a=x(1)}).collect", I got empty results like Array[Unit] = Array((), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()). Did I miss anything here?

Comment: Sorry, I guess you aren't too familiar with Scala. The final statement in a function is the return value. In the case you have listed, the result of a variable assignment is a Unit or (). I have modified my code to make this more obvious on how to FULLY make the change

Comment: Thanks Justin! Yes I am new to Scala so not familar with some concepts. Sorry.

Comment: There is typo in the last line. Should be x +: newCol +: newCol2